# mono compile c# code at run time

Tags: mono

I have some code to compile at runtime as a script and setup file. I know on windows you can use Microsoft.CSharp and System.CodeDom.Compiler to compile code at runtime. And I just want to know if these two namespace exist in mono(I'd like to make a app I'm making sort of cross-platform). I couldn't find a mono api reference which means it has almost everything that .net has?
thanks!

Comment: Please have a look in the mono documentations before: http://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/languages/csharp/
It looks like the Mono.Sharp.dll assembly is what you need.

Comment: And a dll compiled on windows cannot be used on linux with mono, right?

Comment: This should not be a problem. I used c# / mono on raspberry pi for quite a long time now and the only problems I had were when using libraries from mircosoft itself (like Microsoft.* namespace). Take a look here: http://www.mono-project.com/docs/tools+libraries/tools/moma/

Comment: oh, thanks. I've searched and made to understand that the code compiled at runtime by mono may not be as optimized. therefore better not use it...